# How to display some html on every subpage but one?

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am using Laravel to develop my site and I was wondering if there is a way to include some html on every subpage but home page? I know that I can @include anything but I would need to include it on every page and I am looking for some shortcut.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `request` helper for this, for example:

```
@unless(request()->is('/'))
  @include('your view')
@endunless
```

Assuming that your home is the `/` route.

Comment: Amazing, that's what I was looking for. Thanks